# Slim3 add model to app container

Tags: php, slim

I use SLIM 3 framework, long story short, I have problem with adding Model to the container.

It works fine with the controller:

app.php where I inject Controller and Model

```
$container['ExampleController'] = function($container){
    return new \App\Controllers\ExampleController($container);
};

$container['ExampleModel'] = function($container){
    return new \App\Models\ExampleModel($container);
};
```

Then I can use it everywhere when I need to, as long as the container is available:

```
$this->container->ExampleController->method();

$this->container->ExampleModel->method();
```

Controller works fine but Model calls fails, here is the error message I get:

Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException\nMessage: Identifier "ExampleModel" is not defined

As a note, I don't want to use static models.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Might be a typo...

Comment: there's no reason that this could would not work. although w/o seeing where you are getting $this->container from that's about the only thing in question

Comment: You are right guys I misspelled container in app.php, I checked it like 100 times... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I had misspelled container in `app.php` Thanks!